# possible to have an active game running whilst working on the other monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, gaming

I so have I little brother and sister that like to use my dual monitor setup computer and I was wondering if it was possible to have such a system where they could play any steam or epsxe emulated game with the gamepad which would stay active even if I am using the kb/m on the other monitor for other activities?

Comment: try windowed mode for the game

Comment: but that causes the game application to lose focus so im trying to find an application that lets us do both work and for them to play games with the gamepad at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using this program if anyone else whats to do this

http://www.fixitformeplease.com/2013/02/how-to-play-game-on-one-monitor-and-not.html